# merging a collection of `Eigen::VectorXd`s into one large `Eigen::VectorXd`

Tags: c++, eigen

If you go to [this Eigen page](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html), you'll see you can initialize `VectorXd` objects with the `<<` operator. You can also dump a few vector objects into one big `VectorXd` object (e.g. look at the third example in the section called "The comma initializer").

I want to dump a few vectors into a big vector, but I'm having a hard time writing code that will work for an arbitrarily sized collection of vectors. The following doesn't work, and I'm having a hard time writing it in a way that does (that isn't a double for loop). Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // make some random VectorXds
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> vOfV;
    Eigen::VectorXd first(3);
    Eigen::VectorXd second(4);
    first << 1,2,3;
    second << 4,5,6,7;
    vOfV.push_back(first);
    vOfV.push_back(second);

    // here is the problem
    Eigen::VectorXd flattened(7);
    for(int i = 0; i < vOfV.size(); ++i)
        flattened << vOfV[i];

    //shows that this doesn't work
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i)
        std::cout << flattened(i) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to be a bit careful with your wording. An "Eigenvector" is a mathematical term (something that passes a linear operator only scaled)

Comment: @MarcusMüller just edited. hopefully that helps

Comment: That's definitely wrong: `i << vOfV.size()`

Comment: @HenriMenke fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma initializer does not work like that.  You have to fully initialize the matrix from that.  Instead, allocate a large enough vector and iterate and assign the blocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

// http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::VectorXd)

int main()
{
    // make some random VectorXds
    std::vector<Eigen::VectorXd> vOfV;
    Eigen::VectorXd first(3);
    Eigen::VectorXd second(4);
    first << 1,2,3;
    second << 4,5,6,7;
    vOfV.push_back(first);
    vOfV.push_back(second);

    int len = 0;
    for (auto const &v : vOfV)
        len += v.size();

    Eigen::VectorXd flattened(len);

    int offset = 0;
    for (auto const &v : vOfV)
    {
        flattened.middleRows(offset,v.size()) = v;
        offset += v.size();
    }

    std::cout << flattened << "\n";
}
```